# Contact form not sending body and/or subject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, smtp

So I have been making a simple contact form, and have written the code, and it sends the form, I receive it but it comes blank, no subject and no body.

Reviewing similar issues here on stackoverlow I found A LOT of php solutions but no asp.net that would come helpful in my scenario.
Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Send(Contact c)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                MailAddress sender = new MailAddress(c.Email, c.Name);

                MailAddress recipient = new MailAddress("mymail@hotmail.com");

                MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
                Message.From = sender;
                Message.To.Add(recipient);
                Message.Subject = c.Subject;
                Message.Body = c.Msg;
                Message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Port = 587;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("gmail@gmail.com", "password");
                client.Send(Message);

                return Redirect("/Success.html");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return Redirect("/Error.html");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect("www.google.com");
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<form action="/Mail/Send" method="post">
    <div id="glavni">
        <p>
            <label for="TextName">Name:</label>
            <input id="TextName" type="text" name="Name" required autofocus />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="TextSubject">Subject:</label>
            <input id="TextSubject" type="text" name="Subject" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="TextMail">Email:</label>
            <input id="TextMail" type="email" name="Email" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="TextMsg">Unesite Poruku:</label>
            <textarea id="TextMsg" type="text" name="Msg" rows="12" cols="20" ></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </p>
    </div>

</form>
```

MODEL:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Msg {get; set;}

}
```

The Contact Models class props have the same names as html `name` attributes and for some reason sends empty emails.
Hope someone can shed some light!

Comment: You haven't provided a complete example. You need to show your view code as well.

Comment: @mason well since its practice page, I went with simple Empty Page with MVC, I havent used views, just a simple html page. I will link it in a moment!

Comment: You also need to provide the definition for your Contact class.

Comment: @mason edited, this is pretty much the whole app

Comment: Do `c.Subject` and `c.Msg` have value in `Send` method?

Comment: @AliSoltani All the code here is all I have, its the whole app. In case they didnt have value, how would I give it to them?

Comment: Do you go to `Send(Contact c)` by clicking `submit button`?

Comment: I think your model don't post to `Send(Contact c)` action correctly. You can put break point on before `if (ModelState.IsValid)` and check all of properties of `c` has value or not.

Comment: figured out what the problem was, the code works fine, the problem was the library, or the lack of one, for some reason, it wasn't `using Models.Contact` so that was the problem. Sorry for the trouble :/

Answer (score 0):

Default all the actions in controllers are GET methods. So you have to specify the HTTP web method as POST

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Send(Contact c)
```

Comment: But why is it sending me the name and email from the `<input>` but not subject or Msg? Isnt it supposed not to send at all if specification was the problem? I receive the name and the email, but subject and msg are empty :S